# Eye Target/Bases won't Move whenever the Bone is Selected

Tags: rigging

I recently downloaded a free Ko-fi model of Rayman from "Rayman 3: Hoodlum Havoc" for use in Blender. So far, I love the model! It gived me vibes from models from the 90's...if that makes sense.

My big issue with it is the eyes are stuck and can't move. Yes, they DO have bones, target and base for both pupils. Though when selected, they don't move at all!

I tried disconnecting them from the parent head, nothing. I don't if it's because the eyes are a texture image, can't really figure it out.

If anyone could help, that'd be fantastic! Hopefully this has the textures. If not, I'll send them in.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a few things to make progress on your issue:

1. "L_Eye_Base" and "R_Eye_Base" I would think would be inside the head, so that if you re-parent, they will properly move the eye mesh around. I relocated these bones to a better position.
2. your mesh "Eyes_Low" has no vertex groups that would be called by the name of the eye control bones ("*_Eye_Base").  So after repositioning/scaling these *Base* bones to be near the eye mesh, I re-parented *and* cleaned up (removed) vertex groups carefully while in Weight Paint mode (any VG that has no effect is all dark blue.
3. I would think that "_Eye_Base" would have a tracking constraint to follow the "*_Eye_Target" target bones.   I added a Stretch_To constraint to each of the "*_Eye_Base" bone to its respective "*_Eye_Target" bone (added "_IK" to be a Suffix).
4. I also noticed that *IK bones* had *Deform* enabled, so that if you try to re-parent with weights, these will cause distortions during posing, so I undid all those (Select Pattern "*IK*", then in Bone Properties, hold down Alt and disable the Deform check-box).

The mesh materials didn't come with your example, so I couldn't refine and leave that as your exercise, but [image]